# Making a dynamic gridview matrix with 'LIKE'

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Earlier I had a question that and was given some excellent direction from Nikki9696 reguarding dynamic datasource values for my gridview which I'm showing below as I currently have it implemented and working. This works quite well. I have laid out a series of text boxes with label above them directly above my grid view and the user can either leave them blank (resulting in no filtering of records) or provide values that would match items in any one of the corresponding columns represented by the text boxes which would limit that column to only that value as part of the filter and at the same time allow the user to compound multiple boxes to narrow the filter as well. Works really well!

I would really like to take it one step further and have wrestled with it for about week and gotten no where despite experimenting and searching for examples on the web of where someone is doing similar filtering.  I'd like each of these to function instead of being = or null to LIKE or null in that way my users could supply partial information in the text boxes to pull up results rather than an exact match.  I just can't figure out how to alter my WHERE clause to do this.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InventoryList" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMDB_testConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [AssetID], [AssetType], [AssetName], [AssetShortDesc], [AssetLongDesc], [AssetAddNotes], [AssetManuf], [AssetModel], [AssetTag], [AssetSerialNum], [AssetAcqDate], [AssetDTAssetID], [AssetLocGrp], [AssetLoc1], [AssetLoc2], [AssetLoc3], [AssetParent], [AssetStatus], [AssetPropType], [AssetPrimUser], [AssetEntered], [AssetEnteredBy], [AssetOwner], [AssetCompany], [AssetPriIPAddr], [AssetPriMACAddr], [AssetPriOS], [AssetPriOSSP], [AssetNotes], [AssetAdminGrp], [AssetOrgID], [AssetOperType], [AssetOperStatus] FROM [cmdbv_Assets_CInTrac] where AssetID=isnull(@AssetID,AssetID) and AssetName=isnull(@AssetName,AssetName) and AssetType=isnull(@AssetType,AssetType) and AssetManuf=isnull(@AssetManuf,AssetManuf) and AssetModel=isnull(@AssetModel,AssetModel) and AssetTag=isnull(@AssetTag,AssetTag) and AssetSerialNum=isnull(@AssetSerialNum,AssetSerialNum) and AssetDTAssetID=isnull(@AssetDTAssetID,AssetDTAssetID) and AssetLocGrp=isnull(@AssetLocGrp,AssetLocGrp) and AssetLongDesc=isnull(@AssetLongDesc,AssetLongDesc) and AssetOrgID=isnull(@AssetOrgID,AssetOrgID) and AssetPriIPAddr=isnull(@AssetPriIPAddr,AssetPriIPAddr) and AssetStatus=isnull(@AssetStatus,AssetStatus)" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">

<SelectParameters>
       <asp:Controlparameter Name="AssetID" ControlID="AssetIDTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetName" ControlID="AssetNameTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetType" ControlID="AssetTypeTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetShortDesc" ControlID="AssetShortDescTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetManuf" ControlID="AssetManufTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetModel" ControlID="AssetModelTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetTag" ControlID="AssetTagTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetSerialNum" ControlID="AssetSerialNumTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetDTAssetID" ControlID="AssetDTAssetIDTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLocGrp" ControlID="AssetLocGrpTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLongDesc" ControlID="AssetLongDescTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetOrgID" ControlID="AssetOrgIDTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetPriIPAddr" ControlID="AssetPriIPAddrTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetStatus" ControlID="AssetStatusTbx" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

I have tried variations of AssetName='%@AssetName%' and AssetName='%'+@AssetName+'%' as well as sever other contraptions but not had anything that even did anything more than completely blocked all rows from being returned.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated because I really would like to see this on my filters.

Regards,
Ken...

Okay we seem to be making a little progress here but not fully. Here is what I modified the AssetName to reflect in the datasource I may have messed up something on the syntax but I thought I had it exactly as you had stated it.

```
([AssetName] LIKE '%' + CASE WHEN @AssetName is null Then '' Else @AssetName End + '%')
```

Latest Changes to the DataSource per your suggestion:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InventoryList" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMDB_testConnectionString %>' 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [AssetID], [AssetType], [AssetName], [AssetShortDesc], [AssetLongDesc], [AssetAddNotes], [AssetManuf], [AssetModel], [AssetTag], [AssetSerialNum], [AssetAcqDate], [AssetDTAssetID], [AssetLocGrp], [AssetLoc1], [AssetLoc2], [AssetLoc3], [AssetParent], [AssetStatus], [AssetPropType], [AssetPrimUser], [AssetEntered], [AssetEnteredBy], [AssetOwner], [AssetCompany], [AssetPriIPAddr], [AssetPriMACAddr], [AssetPriOS], [AssetPriOSSP], [AssetNotes], [AssetAdminGrp], [AssetOrgID], [AssetOperType], [AssetOperStatus] FROM [cmdbv_Assets_CInTrac]"
    FilterExpression=" Convert(AssetID, 'System.String') LIKE '{0}%' 
    and AssetName LIKE '{1}%' 
    and AssetType LIKE '{2}%' 
    and AssetShortDesc LIKE '{3}%' 
    and AssetManuf LIKE '{4}%' 
    and AssetModel LIKE '{5}%' 
    and AssetTag LIKE '{6}%' 
    and AssetSerialNum LIKE '{7}%' 
    and AssetDTAssetID LIKE '{8}%' 
    and AssetLocGrp LIKE '{9}%' 
    and AssetLongDesc LIKE '{10}%' 
    and AssetOrgID LIKE '{11}%' 
    and AssetPriIPAddr LIKE '{12}%' 
    and Convert(AssetStatus, 'System.string') LIKE '{13}%'">
<FilterParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetID" ControlID="AssetIDTbx" PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetName" ControlID="AssetNameTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetType" ControlID="AssetTypeTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetShortDesc" ControlID="AssetShortDescTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetManuf" ControlID="AssetManufTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetModel" ControlID="AssetModelTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetTag" ControlID="AssetTagTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetSerialNum" ControlID="AssetSerialNumTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetDTAssetID" ControlID="AssetDTAssetIDTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLocGrp" ControlID="AssetLocGrpTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLongDesc" ControlID="AssetLongDescTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetOrgID" ControlID="AssetOrgIDTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetPriIPAddr" ControlID="AssetPriIPAddrTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetStatus" ControlID="AssetStatusTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
 </FilterParameters> 
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: have you tried this  WHERE ([AssetName] LIKE '%' + @AssetName+ '%')

Comment: Yep, yields zero return records when left blank or when data is part or an exact match is filled in the text box.

Comment: That's because you use isnull function which you specify a certain value and at the same time you want Sql to return every possible record it finds if the AssetName partially match. That's where your query wont return records.  In this case you could use OR instead of AND. Having said that. I cannot understand fully based on your question what results you are expecting from the query above :)

Comment: As it currently stand the datasource allow blank return of all record or filtering by supplying data elements to these columns.  So when we have a match the column is limited to only those rows that contain the value matching the value retained in the parameter. Users can do this for any number of text boxes that correspond to various columns. 

What I'm wishing to accomplish it the same basic function but instead of equivalence, to the textbox contents I want to do a LIKE function instead so that we can match on partials.

Comment: Alright. Could you update your post with the query you attempted so I can check the whole statement!

Comment: All I did when testing that particular variation was alter the segment of the existing line from 
     >> and AssetName=isnull(@AssetName,AssetName) <<  to   >> and ([AssetName] LIKE '%'+@AssetName+'%') << .  My thought was that LIKE being what it is that with the two wild cards either side that with a null value in @AssetName this would be effectively a wild card for any values and match everything.  So blank would match all. and 'lap' would match 'Laptop'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117108/discussion-between-ken-carter-and-gh-karim).

Comment: @GH_Karim, Check what I just edit to the first post... that is what I edited into as a test based on your answer above. I thought I had it exact but maybe I messed up something. It works blank to return all records, it works exact to match a specific criteria, but it doesn't do a like on a partial so 'lap' will no return all laptops. just leaves an empty gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to pass the value as string.empty and also you need to allow covertingEmptyStringToNull for each and every QueryStringParameter.

So the steps are as simple as the following:

1- Add  `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"` for each `QueryStringParameter` in you query. The following example shows how your `QueryStringParameter` elements should look like:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="@AssetName" 
                          DefaultValue="" 
                          Name="AssetName" 
                          Type="String" 
                          ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true">
</asp:QueryStringParameter>
```

2- Now, In order to allow string.Empty to be passed in the queryString in the `SqlDataSource`, you can use [`CASE WHEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in your `Where` clause. The following is an example to demonstrate this. Then in your scenario you can apply this to each parameter.

```
SELECT [AssetName]
FROM [cmdbv_Assets_CInTrac] 
WHERE ([AssetName] LIKE '%' + 
CASE WHEN @AssetName is NULL 
Then '' 
Else @AssetName 
End + '%')
```

Comment: @GH_Karim the problem with this solution is that I 14 different conditions that are being tested against.  Would I then have to put an and after each and build a similar structure for each of these 14 column checks?  I presume I would!

Comment: Also, is there a typo I n your last line there should that read: Else @AssetName End + '%')

Comment: Correct!  that was a typo . sorry I just updated the answer.

Comment: yes the structure will have to be repeated  for each parameter you send. However, if you don't mind assigning the SELECT statement from the code instead of using SqlDataSource then you will not need the structure as you will easily be assigning the value of the parameters to string.empty.

Comment: Your last comment; if you go back and look at the existing asp.datasource I have in the live code you'll see that the select includes all 14 of the columns so that if a use supplies data for any of the text boxes on the page they will act as a collective filter.   for example if I searched for my name in PrimeUser and HP as the manufacture I could find all those assets that were assigned to me that were made by HP with the current code. Now what I'm shooting for is to be able to simply put 'Ken' in Primeuser and see all the HP gear assigned to everyone named ken. Let me play with this! Thanks!

Comment: By the way: The info on QueryStringParameter I already have in my code but because it gets so garbled up I didn't included it here. Without that the original code would not have worked.

Comment: I've learned through doing some further testing that 'Lap'+'%' has the same issue where no records are returned. so apparently the failure is that it isn't reading the % as a wild card.

Comment: Ok. how about we make sure if what you said. I suggest that you hard code it in your query as following .. so try  ([AssetName] LIKE '%lap'%')

Comment: Just tried that without success as well.  I've pretty much confirmed that this is ignoring % as a wildcard.  Either that or we are not successfully affixing the % character to the variable as a single string value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117146/discussion-between-gh-karim-and-ken-carter).

Answer (score 0):

To map LIKE directly with a textbox, you can also use [FilterExpression][1]. For example, assuming you have the following `Textbox` for filtering

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can code your `SqlDataSource` as shown in the following example:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="gridDataSource" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMDB_testConnectionString %>'
       SelectCommand="SELECT [AssetName] FROM [cmdbv_Assets_CInTrac]"
       FilterExpression="AssetName LIKE '{0}%'">
       <FilterParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetName" ControlID="searchTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
       </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In your scenario you will have to create `ControlParameter` for each column you want to map to a `TextBox`. Make sure you map by the textbox control id as shown in the example above.

**Update 2**
Your statement should look like the following.. In your answer you repeated `FilterExpression` and didn't increment the `{0}` for each column. So here's how your `SqlDataSource` should be

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InventoryList" runat="server" 
ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMDB_testConnectionString %>'
SelectCommand="SELECT [AssetID], [AssetType], [AssetName], [AssetShortDesc],
 [AssetLongDesc], [AssetAddNotes], [AssetManuf], [AssetModel], [AssetTag]
[AssetSerialNum], [AssetAcqDate], [AssetDTAssetID], [AssetLocGrp], [AssetLoc1], 
[AssetLoc2], [AssetLoc3], [AssetParent], [AssetStatus], [AssetPropType], 
[AssetPrimUser], [AssetEntered], [AssetEnteredBy], [AssetOwner], [AssetCompany], 
[AssetPriIPAddr], [AssetPriMACAddr], [AssetPriOS], [AssetPriOSSP], [AssetNotes], 
[AssetAdminGrp], [AssetOrgID], [AssetOperType], [AssetOperStatus] 
FROM  [cmdbv_Assets_CInTrac]" 

FilterExpression=" Convert(AssetID , 'System.String') LIKE '{0}%' 
AND AssetName LIKE '{1}%' 
And AssetType LIKE '{2}%'
AND AssetShortDesc LIKE '{3}%' 
AND AssetManuf LIKE '{4}%' 
AND AssetModel LIKE '{5}%'
AND AssetTag LIKE '{6}%' 
AND Convert(AssetSerialNum , 'System.String') LIKE '{7}%' 
AND Convert(AssetDTAssetID , 'System.String') LIKE '{8}%' 
AND AssetLocGrp LIKE '{9}%'
AND AssetLongDesc LIKE '{10}%'
AND Convert( AssetOrgID, 'System.String') LIKE '{11}%' 
AND AssetPriIPAddr LIKE '{12}%'
AND AssetStatus LIKE '{13}%'">
<FilterParameters>
<asp:Controlparameter Name="AssetID" ControlID="AssetIDTbx" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetName" ControlID="AssetNameTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetType" ControlID="AssetTypeTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetShortDesc" ControlID="AssetShortDescTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetManuf" ControlID="AssetManufTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetModel" ControlID="AssetModelTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetTag" ControlID="AssetTagTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetSerialNum" ControlID="AssetSerialNumTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetDTAssetID" ControlID="AssetDTAssetIDTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLocGrp" ControlID="AssetLocGrpTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetLongDesc" ControlID="AssetLongDescTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetOrgID" ControlID="AssetOrgIDTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetPriIPAddr" ControlID="AssetPriIPAddrTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="AssetStatus" ControlID="AssetStatusTbx"  PropertyName="Text" />
 </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I just inserted (above in the original post under the asp:DataSource where it shows up in my code) my existing ControlParameters that are in my existing code.   This way you can see it as it appears.

Comment: Just did a test where I replaced the conditional for AssetName with a simple LIKE formula to see if I could get the wild cards to work here is what I used: AssetName LIKE ('%'+@AssetName+'%')  then ran the page. put in Lap got no return even though 'Laptops were present in the column and then changed that to Laptop and still no returns.
 I then re-edited it to read: AssetName LIKE ('%Lap%') in order to force feed the value into the datasource and it still came up with no results.

Comment: Mr Ken. your updates indicates that you have not implemented the SqlDataSource as I suggested above. I would recommend replacing the SqlDataSource you updated your original post with the one I specifically answered with. Copy and paste it and only try it against AssetName. I am quite confident it will return the values as expected

Comment: I'm having trouble with the interface here and missing parts of your messages you're suggesting insert a filter expression then?

Comment: This has only one of the 14 columns how would it work with the other 13?... I'm trying to test without blowing up my existing code.

Comment: Yes. I assumed that you'd want to test it first against only one column to make sure it works first. however you can repeat the process of one column to the other 13 columns. and then you'd increment {0} as shown above for each column.

Comment: :) hehe okay take a look at my failing code I just put up .. I think you just gave me the answer ... the {0} needs to be incremented to {1} and {2} etc... correct?  That's why it is broken?  I can't test one I have an entire gridview here to deal with.

Comment: Got rid of the error... but getting odd results.. testing further shows that typing in the text boxes does noting to narrow the data whatsoever. So the filter is non functional. I'm updating the current post to show the code as it is.

Comment: @KenCarter Just updated my answer with what you exactly would use. Please notice that I add Convert functions for each column which its type is int (Integer). And I made a guess on each column. So you need to make the right adjustments.

Comment: I updated the only two columns which were integers in the filter which are AssetID and AssetStatus none of the others are integers. The result is that the filter seems to be totally nonfunctional. with or without data in text boxes the results are the same regardless of how much the information does or does not match the data in the columns. Like it is being totally ignored.

Comment: I really cannot think of any reason why "Like" is being ignored!!. I created a test project and replicated your scenario but with less columns and it works as expected. There are lots of reasons that can contribute in these results.  could be  the user inputs from the text boxes or the data being joined with "And " logic. Sorry!!!

Comment: is there some sort of include that I'm missing or something that understands the notation or something?  This is baffling. We've been dancing all around it and this should be working.

Comment: I would really recommend that you isolate the problem. Start by testing it against one column with a set of data  you know must return as a result. also you can try the query  in the database itself forgetting SqlDataSource. Here's a link I found that could help you. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-LIKE-in-SelectCommand-of-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Since management wanted me to do a dog and pony show with it and I pasted the old source back in the entire thing is broken now I can't get any of it to run without bogus errors to flag about 'Incorrect syntax near nvarchar when I don't have nvarchar in my code anywhere is driving me crazy.  I've tried back rev'ing. Only thing that works to strip it back to no where clause at all. That's not going to fly at all. Grrrrrr <sigh>!  Will let you know more as I beat my head against this today.

Comment: I just updated the last version of the SqlDataSource per our discussion in the original post About to head to lunch here. After lunch I'm planning on striping back this to single column filter and play with that to see what kind of results I get.

Comment: Single column filtering made no difference. My code continues to ignore the 'like filter'.  All data is returned from the query regardless of what is input into the text box that is targeted in the filter which I narrow to. I'm about ready to give up on doing this as it seems hopeless at this point. GH and I have spent far too much time on it and for some reason the wild cards are being ignored. For that matter the entire filter is.

Comment: If you tested it with the answer you updated your original post with then that one was full or syntax errors. I have sent you earlier in the chat the answer you should use with no syntax error.